# What is the best way to make a shopping cart page in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I have a simple shopping cart page in React Native app and I have "plus/minus" buttons for amount of each item.
I have 2 questions:

1- What is the best way to update items price when I tap to change the amount of each item? Should each price be an State?

2- Actually, I can statically change amount of each item in cart, but when I change any RN State, all items amounts I've changed is lost. How can I save my actions for not lose it all at states change?

```
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.items} product="1">
            <Avatar
                size="large"
                rounded
                source={{ uri: "https://picsum.photos/80/80?random" }}
            />
            <View style={styles.text}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Uva Prata</Text>
                <Text style={styles.price}>R$ <Text style={styles.money}>4,90</Text> <Text style={styles.unit}>/ kg</Text></Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.amount}>

                <NumericInput rounded 
                                onChange={ } />
            </View>
        </View>
```

...other view
...other view
...other view
...

Comment: You need to show the code you're using to change the state.

Comment: If you ask me shopping cart state should most likely be available throughout your entire application, since a user could always go back to the shop to add some stuff. So I would put this kind of information in a global state, like redux or mobx

Comment: thank you dentemm, I will study about redux.